# ImportError: cannot import name Gdl from gi.repository

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, python3, docking

Trying to import the [Gnome Docking Library](https://developer.gnome.org/gdl/stable/) I get the exception:

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gdl
...
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Gdl
ImportError: cannot import name Gdl
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the gdl-3 package is installed for you system, on Ubuntu that's:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gdl-3
```

Heres the package listing on debian.org:
https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Gdl-3.typelib&mode=path&suite=unstable&arch=any

Credit to nemequ on irc.gnome.org for the references and solution.

Comment: P.S. I ended up not using GDL because it wasn't the dockable-toolbar tool I wanted; GIMP uses it to dock large vertical-oriented panes, where I wanted to dock thin horizontal panes, which it does not do very well.